# Android SQLite Query Syntax causing sqlite.SQLiteException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

So i have a section in my database where i need to do a join the tables look like this...

```
 ______________           _______________
|Vehicle       |         |Car            |
|--------------|         |---------------|
|_id        PK |         |_id         PK |
|Warehouse     |         |VehicleId   FK |
|Location      |         |Make           |
|VehicleKey    |         |Model          |
|______________|         |_______________|
```

The Car VehicleID Foreign key is from the Vehicle Primary key. What I want to return is a cursor for each vehicle.

Warehouse Location Make Model

I'm not sure how I would construct the SQLite statement, can anyone give me a hand?? So far I have this as my method to retrieve all of the vehicles

```
public Cursor getCars()
{
    Cursor c = database.query("SELECT Vehicle.Warehouse, Vehicle.Location, Vehicle.VehicleKey, Car.Make," +
                    " Car.Make FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Car" +
                    "ON Vehicle Vehicle._id = Car.VehicleId",
            null, null,null,null,null,null,null);

    return c;
}
```

I'm pretty new to this way of doing database manipulation as I would normally have it done for me by a builder as I have only ever worked in c#. Can anyone help me out trying to get the correct results?

There is an error produced, but I think it's because of syntax of the sqlite statement

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SELECT Vehicle.Warehouse.........
```

Comment: code in your exception and that you have posted is different. It doesn't have `SELECT *` statement

Comment: For some reason when i use .query() it puts in that at the beginning and im not sure why?

Comment: **1** `query()` doesn't work with SQL queries, while `rawQuery()` does. **2** `... ON Vehicle Vehicle._id = Patient.VehicleId` You don't have a table named **Patient**

Comment: Yeah that was a typo i have changed. Also i am unable to use rawQuery() as i need to stick to API15 not 16

Comment: I use `rawQuery()` since API Level **8**. And still keeping using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no overloaded methods for `query` that accept a Sql String as a parameter.

See the documentation for the `query` methods here.:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

The first parameter is usually the table name.

The system is trying to build a Sql query using your whole query as the table name therefore you get a query such as "SELECT * FROM SELECT Vehicle..." etc

Either supply the correct parameters to the `query` method or use the `rawQuery` method which expects a standard Sql string.

Comment: How would i do this without using rawQuery() ? I have looked at doc but closest thing to what i need is rawQuery(), but its an API above what i need to write in.

Comment: The answer I gave is specific to the question you asked. If you have a new question, you should post a it to the site. Adding additional questions in the comments gets confusing for future readers.  For the record though, both methods return a cursor so I do not see why you would want to avoid the `rawQuery` method when that is clearly more suited to your needs given that you already have a raw sql query to supply to it.

Comment: Thanks, it was a requirement for the project that would only allow me to develop at API15.  Or else i would use your answer as is an solve the issue

Comment: My answer solves the issue even if you want to use only the query method.  As I said, supply it with the correct arguments and not a Sql query which you can only use with the rawQuery method. By the way, rawQuery is supported all the way from Api level 1.  Please read the documentation.

Comment: Hmm, il go try again, whenever i try using rawQuery() android studio flags it as unsupported and asks to upgrade to 16. Im not entirely sure how to get it with query() but il go over again and see if i can spot it. Thanks

Comment: public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs) API 1

Comment: public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal) API 16

Comment: Ahh, i didnt see that, yes i must have overloaded it to incompatible method.  Thanks again, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Please read the instructions for this site. Of all the questions you have asked, you have not accepted any of the answers you have been given. People will be less likely to assist you in future if you do not give credit for the answers you receive. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String table = "Vehicle v INNER JOIN Car c ON Vehicle v._id = c.VehicleId";
    String[] columns = new String[]{ "v.Warehouse", "v.Location", "v.VehicleKey", "c.Make"};
    /*String where condition for example "where  v.id = 1" 3rd parameter is your where codition in your db.query function */
/*db.query with where condtion :  Cursor c = db.query(table,columns,"where  v.id = 1",null,null,null,null,null);*/
    Cursor c = db.query(table,columns,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

Please review your query since i don't see patient Table in your join

Comment: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "v": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT v.Warehouse, v.Location.......`  When i try this solution

Comment: can u put a debugger der n check wat query is being made n plsss post the entirexception if u can

Answer (score -2):

You may edit your query using this syntax :

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

Comment: This is not an answer.